# How to add formula to a cell that has been transposed

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a cell that I transposed using =TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(IPHONES!B82,"/")), Now i would like to manipulate that same cell using another formula, but it wont let me add another formula. I would like to add IF formula, like If greater than 100 add 5 for example. How would i be able to add another formula please help.

Comment: Put some sample data here then expected output. Not very clear but you can try something like `=IF(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(IPHONES!B82,"/"))>100,TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(IPHONES!B82,"/"))+5,TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(IPHONES!B82,"/")))`

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(IPHONES!B82, "/"))>100,
          TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(IPHONES!B82, "/"))+5,
          TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(IPHONES!B82, "/"))))
```